# How do I have optional nested resources submitted through a form in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Iam using simple_form.  The user can create a message.  Optionally, they can attach a contact.  Right now, if they don't attach a contact, a new Contact is still created?

How can I only associate and create a new Contact when that Contact portion of the form is filled out?

Here is the form I use now:

```
1 = simple_form_for @message, :remote => true do |f|
  2   #message_form
  3     = f.error_messages
  4     %p
  5       = f.input :account_name, :url => autocomplete_account_name_messages_path, :size => 40, :as => :autocomplete
  6     %p
  7       = f.input :subject
  8       %br 
  9       = f.input :body, :as => :text, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 5, :cols => 30, :maxlength => 140  }
 10     = hidden_field_tag :sender_id, params[:sender_id]
 11     = hidden_field_tag :receiver_id, params[:id]
 12 
 13     = f.submit 'Give'
 14     = f.submit 'Request'
 15     
 16     #add_contact_btn
 17       = link_to "Add Contact"
 18     
 19       #contact_form
 20         = simple_fields_for :contact do |fc|
 21           %p
 22             = fc.input :first_name
 23           %p
 24             = fc.input :last_name
 25             = fc.input :email
 26             = fc.input :title
 27             = fc.input :office_phone
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be done in your model, something like:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |c| c[:first_name].blank? && c[:last_name].blank? }
```

Or whatever condition you prefer.

The dirty way, while Rails bugs are being fixed. In your model:

```
after_save :check_nil_contact

def check_nil_contact
  if contact.first_name.blank?
    contact.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: should the association be message has_one contact or message belongs_to contact?

Comment: I always had `has_one`like here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html But I don't think it makes a difference

Comment: I see -- I tried belongs_to...it still creates an empy contact associated with it....I'm trying to have it so that if it is blank, there's no contact created or associated, and if there's a value, then create it..thanks for your help.

Comment: I used belongs_to because I have a contact_id attribute in Message

Comment: hmmm, indeed I had a problem using Rails 3.0.4: there was a bug causing the `reject_if` fail when used alongside `allow_destroy`. I hacked the model and add this verification in a `after_save` callback. I haven't checked if it has been fixed since. So 1) remove `allow_destroy` OR 2) use a `after_save` callback (tell me if you need the code I wrote)

Comment: should I change from Rails version?  I think I am 3.0.3....I don't think I can switch to 3.1 yet because I'm unclear on the other dependencies... :( thanks!

Comment: just copy/pasted what I did while waiting for fix

Comment: okay so it's really a raise error...how will I know when to go back to what you suggested?  thanks!

Comment: how is 'contacts' getting assigned the value through the nested simple_form?

Comment: am I doing the nested form correctly, I am still getting a nil value, although I do so params being passed through.

Comment: I changed this to accepts_nested_attributes :contacts (plural) instead of singular since message has_many contacts?  But it's still not storing it....?

Comment: sidenote: why did you just delete your question about partials?

Comment: well, pretty unfair for people who took time to answer it.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand your question anymore: 1)you shifted from a one-one relationship to a one-to-many (no real impact but it's still weird) 2) you complained it was storing empty objects and now you complain it's not storing anything

Comment: I don't think anyone answered it -- I deleted it in 3 minutes -- stackoverflow doesn't allow you to delete if someone posted an answer.

Comment: I did answer :) well could you clarify this question?

Comment: oh...sorry...did you answer in the comments or in the actual answer?  Yes, let me change the question.  All I want to do is have a nested form....let me make some adjustments, thank you

Comment: @Angela let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1194/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-angela)